# How does using loaders in webpack affect your build file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, frontend, create-react-app

When I write a traditional web-app (MVC-type), assets are served from the public folder (usually) but I notice in React there is not public folder (using create-react-app)... Instead I have use loaders.

Are the loaded files included as part of the bundle file that Webpack generates for React once you do a build? Does that mean it's best if I use a CDN for for static assets instead of using image loaders because it'll increase the size of my builds?

Or what are just some best-practices when handling static assets when using create-react-app?

Thanks ahead if you have any input! Just trying to understand better...

Comment: loaders just build static assets, and in production, you load those static assets normally. suggested reading: https://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `create-react-app`, and you import images into your JS files, those images will be loaded using the `url-loader` webpack module ([link](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) to its github), which either embeds your images directly into the HTML using DataURLs (more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)) or the images are put into their own separate file if they are bigger than 10,000 bytes.

The relevant code is in [webpack.config.prod.js](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js):

```
{
    test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
    loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    },
},
```

Per the configuration above, larger images (above 10,000 bytes) will be placed in the `static/media` folder.

This is the behavior if you import your images into your JS files like below:

```
import img from './file.png'
```

If you are not importing your images, then it is completely up to you to choose how organize your images. For example, you could place your images in a `/static/images` folder in your root directory, and reference those images like so:

```
<img src="/static/images/logo.png" />
```

In terms of best practice, you can make an argument either way. One key benefit of using `url-loader` is that smaller images are embedded into your HTML, which should help with performance. On the other hand, serving your images from a CDN can potentially serve your large images faster than your application's server.

Comment: Thanks so much for the nice explanation! This is the kind of detail I was looking for!